# Pausing and then resuming a piped command

Tags: curl, xargs, parallelism

I'm downloading **a lot** of data for my research. The data is being downloaded on one of my campus's supercomputers, but data downloads are interrupted every hour. When the OS pauses the pipeline, I have to delete all of the lines of the text file that represent the files that have already been downloaded. Not hard, but annoying and I would prefer not to do that. Here is how I am downloading everything

`cat subset.txt | tr -d '\r' | xargs -P 4 -n 1 curl -LJO -s -n --globoff -c ~/.urs_cookies -b ~/.urs_cookies`

Each url is passed to `curl` and `xargs` gives me 4 parallel downloads. Is there a way to pause the entire pipeline and continue the pipeline later on?

Comment: You can send SIGSTOP and SIGCONT to the `cat` process, if this is what you mean.

Comment: Hm. I shall try it out. Thanks

Comment: That does not seem to work. I think I need to pause `xargs` instead since all of the URLs have already been processed by the first 2 steps of the pipe

Comment: Yeah. I forgot about the buffering, so cat may already have sent the next urls, so `xargs` would be the better target.

Comment: What do you mean by "the OS pauses the pipeline"? Are the processes in the pipeline actually killed? If not, why are files re-downloaded (I assume this is the reason for you to remove lines from your text file)? And, if yes, how can suspending the pipeline help?

Comment: Look at `--continue-at  -` to continue where a download left off. In principle you then dont need to edit `subset.txt`. Beware: remote server has to support this.

Comment: `curl` is able to parallelize downloads and read URLs from a file; replacing the whole pipeline with a single `curl` invocation/process will also make the use of signals (if really needed) easier  -- that's why I asked about the pipeline "being paused".

Comment: There is a 60 minute CPU process time limit enforced by the OS, according to the documentation of this supercomputer put out by the IT department. I was under the impression that `curl` still attempts to download the file with the `--continute-at`, but perhaps I am wrong. I was also unaware that curl would parallellize anything. I don't see anything in the man page about curl being parallel

Comment: As far as how pausing would help: it might not. I figured that pausing might reset the runtime that the OS checks to enforce the time limit. It's very likely it won't matter, but I won't know until I try.

Comment: `--continue-at  -` will have to do at least one access to the server per existing file to see if anymore needs to be read. If you r OS is killing processes you will never know if that last file being downloaded is complete or not.

Comment: Right, see the slow part here does not actually seem to be the data download, it's the processing that the remote server has to do to prepare the file it returns. I am operating under the assumption that all files on the disk are complete. If, after all the downloads are done, I find a file that is incomplete, then I can reinitiate a download for those files. There will be far fewer files that are incomplete than are complete.

Comment: Have you considered a different approach? AFIAK, you cannot 'pause' a single part of a pipeline. The entire pipeline is processed and dispatched in an "all or nothing" manner. What you might do is make a listfile of the files you want, and then loop through the listing file--skipping the download of a file if the file exists, and download only that one file if it does not. The process the next file in the list the same way. I might even get around the 60 minute limit, since each invoked curl process starts fresh. (Your download driver script might still get killed, though.)

Comment: You could also modify the method I suggested in to a "cron job" that executes once per minute. It will need to check if the previous execution has finished (and do nothing if it is still in progress--otherwise, you will have many cron jobs running trying to do the same thing!). If no file is currently being downloaded, then it can select _one_ file to download, and exit when done. Let future cron executions download the next file, and the next... (I leave the process of ensuring only one download at a time as an exercise for you to learn ;-) )

Answer (score 2):

You could let `curl` do the [parallel downloads](https://curl.se/docs/manpage.html#-Z) with the `-Z` option. You need [at least version 7.66.0](https://everything.curl.dev/cmdline/urls#do-the-transfers-in-parallel) for that, but note that they have added more parallel related flags in the versions after 7.66.

The bare bones command would be:

```
curl --config myconfig.txt -Z ...
```

where `myconfig.txt` has the list of urls in this format (you can add other flags, for example to rename output, resume downloads, ...):

```
url = "http://example.com/a"
url = "http://example.com/j"
```

You can find more information on the config file [at their site](https://everything.curl.dev/cmdline/configfile).